# Extracting values from an excel table to build a graph

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have the risk register shown as an excel table. I want to extract the entry corresponding to a specific KRA value and plot its maximum on a graph. I need the method to be automatic so that any addition to the risk register causes the graph to update.

### [image: risk register]

Example:

For the shown risk register, I will have 3 axes on a radar chart labelled "Technology", "Infrastructure" and "Disaster(Tsunami)" each having corresponding values 16,8 and 5 (the maximum Total Rating per KRA). How do I do this?

PS: I've been trying to use Vlookup formulas (but getting cell reference errors) and match-index (does not automatically update), but I would welcome any answers using VBA.

---

My formulae were (present in a another worksheet) :

in cell A1: `=VLOOKUP("Technology",tblRiskRegister[Key Risk Area (KRA)],tblRiskRegister[Total Rating])` which gives me a cell reference error even when I enter it as an array formula (Ctrl+Shift-Enter)

Comment: it's surely possible to configure `vlookup()` to work well, and also strange that your `match()` formula doesn't update automatically, posting them we could help you to fix them. VBA: if you can do something easily with formulas then it's generally not a good approach to code it, also we aren't a free code writing service, you need to put some effort and ask for help if you stuck, if you need the full code then please look for professional programmers.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I will post my formulae shortly; just to clarify, the "update" is when i add a row to the risk register and there is no `match` formula in the corresponding cell in another worksheet (where the values that will build up the radar graph and the graph itself, are) of the same excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with pivot chart: put KRA to "axis fields" and total rating to values (use max function).
To facilitate updating of your chart convert your data range to data table first so you won't need to change source data range when you enter data.
Also you can add very simple code to your sheets module to update chart when data changes. (just change "radar_sheet" to the name of your sheet containing the chart)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Sheets("radar_sheet").PivotTables(1).RefreshTable
End Sub
```

Comment: The PivotChart is a very nice thought; Thumbs up! I haven't tried the VBA module yet though do I add it to the chart worksheet or to the whole excel file?

Comment: you need to add it to the worksheet containing your data to make it run when you change any data.